# Java Applet on Tomcat using servlet?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, applet

I have a working applet on my Tomcat server but in this applet I need to save information locally.

I used writefile.. and it was working on eclipse, but it doesn't work like that on a server..

I did a lot of research to do a servlet to be able to save the information in an html file. I know I have to use a Post, but I don't know how.

I also want to know if the servlet is just a Servlet.class placed in my tomcat folder and how to call it from my java application?

Comment: Provide your code, then you can get more help.

Comment: Applets are old technology by now in my estimation. If a site requires Java applets, I won't go to it.  Java is fine on the server-side, but the ActiveX plugin in the browser that runs Applets on the client-side is insecure. You build a site based around Applets, and you're likely to have wasted your time as anyone security conscious will avoid it, and your average clueless user will not even have Java installed on their machine.

Answer (score 1):

> First, I used writefile.. and it was working on eclipse, but it doesn't work like that on a server..

Continue using that.  The applet will need to be digitally signed before it can be successfully deployed, so if it declares `all-permissions` in the manifest, it should be able to write to the local file system.